# OpenJDK NIO method undefined

Tags: eclipse, nio, java

I am having a problem when using methods from the java.nio.file.Files class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile) using OpenJDK javaSE-1.7 in Eclipse.

After an import:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
```

I cannot call methods like:

```
isDirectory(Path, LinkOption);
```

or

```
isRegularFile(Path, LinkOption);
```

Is there something wrong with OpenJDK? Or has anyone else encountered this? I am guessing this is a widely used class so it must work without a problem.

I am sure the right JRE is being used. Also other methods coming from `java.nio.file.FileSystems` and `java.nio.file.Path` do work.

Comment: What happens when you try to call those methods?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct import for `Path`? There is an `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path` which is not correct (must be `java.nio.file.Path`).

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the method names with `Files.`?

Answer (score 2):

What you want, most probably, is `import static java.nio.file.Files.*;`

When you just import the `Files` class you have to prefix the method invocations like `Files.isDirectory(p, o);`. To enable invocation without prefixing with the class name you need the static import to import the static members of the class `Files`.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot that this is java and you need an object or a class to run methods. I get things mixed up from time to time. Thanks a lot!